# PHP cURL POST via Oracle RightNow

Tags: php, oracle, curl

I have a CPM that is invoked on the 'update' trigger in Oracle's Service Cloud. 
It takes some info from Service Cloud and sends it via cURL to Eloqua. It's also Asynchronously executed.

It does work, but not consistently. It appears as though to get consistent results, I need to wait ~5 minutes before executing another 'LIVE' test. (The test harness in Process Designer works every time however).

So although my tests are correct, something is holding up multiple requests when the code is deployed live. I get 2 posts before it doesn't post any more data.

Thanks in advance

```
/**
 * CPMObjectEventHandler: ServiceCloudToEloqua
 * Package: RN
 * Objects: Opportunity
 * Actions: Update
 * Version: 1.2
 * Purpose: Submit form containing information to eloqua
  */
use \RightNow\Connect\v1_2 as RNCPHP;
use \RightNow\CPM\v1 as RNCPM;



/**
 * Handler class for CPM
 */
class ServiceCloudToEloqua implements RNCPM\ObjectEventHandler {
    /**
     * Apply CPM logic to object.
     * @param int $runMode
     * @param int $action
     * @param object $obj
     * @param int $cycles
     */

    public static function apply($run_mode, $action, $obj, $n_cycles) {
        if ($n_cycles !== 0) {
            return;
        }

        function sendToEloqua($data, $urlString) {
            //open connection
            if (!function_exists("\curl_init")) {
                \load_curl();
            }
            if (!function_exists("curl_init")) {
                load_curl();
            }

            $curl_connection = curl_init($urlString);

            //configure the relevant curl settings
            $options = array (
                CURLOPT_URL                 => $urlString,
                CURLOPT_FAILONERROR         => true,
                CURLOPT_HEADER              => 0,
                CURLOPT_NOBODY              => true, //don't send body as return data
                CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT   => 60,
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS   => 2000,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER      => true,
                CURLOPT_POST                => true,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS          => $data,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER      => false, //ignore ssl verify
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST      => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION      => true
            );

            curl_setopt_array($curl_connection, $options);

            //execute the post
            $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

            //Check for errors and display the error message(curl can't connect to eloqua)
            if(curl_error($curl_connection)) {
                $error = 'error:' . curl_error($curl_connection);
            }
            else {
                echo "Data transfer: Success ";
            }

            //close the connection
            curl_close($curl_connection);

            echo $data;
        }

        if (RNCPM\ActionUpdate == $action) {
            try {
                //create empty array to store values
                $objectData = array();
                //dump values into array
                $objectData[emailAddress] = $obj->PrimaryContact->Contact->Emails[0]->Address;
                $objectData[randomNumber] = rand(0,100);
                $objectData[summary] = $obj->Summary;
                /*Custom Fields
                $email = $obj->CustomFields->c->st_pref_1_code
                */
                //print_r($obj);
                $urlString = 'https://s801.t.eloqua.com/e/f2?elqFormName=processDesigner&elqSiteID=801';
                $data = '&randomNumber='    . $objectData[randomNumber] . 
                        '&emailAddress='    . $objectData[emailAddress] . 
                        '&summary='         . $objectData[summary];

                $obj->save();
                RNCPHP\ConnectAPI::commit();
                sendToEloqua($data, $urlString);

            }
            //if an exception occurs, catch the 'thrown' exception
            catch(Exception $e) {
                echo "Exception Caught: " . $e->getMessage();           
            }
        }
    }
}



/**
 * CPM test harness
 */
class ServiceCloudToEloqua_TestHarness implements RNCPM\ObjectEventHandler_TestHarness {

    static $inc_invented = NULL;

    public static function setup() {
        $inc = RNCPHP\Opportunity::fetch(1105653);
        static::$inc_invented = $inc;
        return;
    }

    public static function fetchObject($action, $object_type) {
        return (static::$inc_invented);
    }

    public static function validate($action, $object) {
        return (true);
    }

    public static function cleanup() {
        return;
    }
}
```